How to initialize an array of structs containing union in C++11?
My question is tightly coupled with my another question. I have been struggling with initialization of an array containing struct members with union.
Let's say I have following declarations in C++11
enum class FilterType { kLowPass, kAverage };

enum class FilterLowPassConfig {
  k1kHzLowPass = 0,
  k10kHzLowPass = 1,
  k20kHzLowPass = 2,
  k40kHzLowPass = 3
};

enum class FilterAverageConfig {
  kWindowSize256 = 0,
  kWindowSize128 = 1,
  kWindowSize64 = 2,
  kWindowSize32 = 3
};

union FilterConfig {
  FilterLowPassConfig low_pass_config;
  FilterAverageConfig average_config;
};

struct FilterSelect
{
  FilterType filter_type;
  FilterConfig filter_config;
};

Now I define an array:
FilterSelect filter_select[2];

What shall I do to be able initialize the array filter_select with brace-enclosed initializer list? I have been looking for a solution without boost::variant and boost::variant2.

If you have c++20 as an option, use designated initializers - https://www.cppstories.com/2021/designated-init-cpp20/

Repeating my previous comment on the other question: Without adding constructors, you can only initialize the first union member. Is that sufficient for you? If so, the straight-forward brace nesting through the aggregate layers is correct. Otherwise, you need to add constructors to the union or use assignment instead of initialization.

@user17732522 thank you for your reactions. I need to initialize the first and also the second member of the union. May I ask you for clarification of the idea with constructor?

Give FilterConfig constructors FilterConfig(FilterLowPassConfig low_pass_config) : low_pass_config(low_pass_config) {} and FilterConfig(FilterAverageConfig average_config) : average_config(average_config) {} and then passing any of the enumerators for the union will work as expected. However, as mentioned in the other comments, the clean solution is to make FilterSelect a proper class which maintains its invariants, which amounts to re-implementing a kind of (specialized) variant. Otherwise a user can make a mistake by mismatching filter_type, breaking the invariant.

Thank you very much for explanation. I'm sorry but I still don't understand the clean solution with the FilterSelect proper class. May I ask you for a code snippet for this approach?

You can use a Brace-Enclosed List
FilterSelect filter_select[2] = {
    {FilterType::kLowPass, {.low_pass_config = FilterLowPassConfig::k10kHzLowPass}},
    {FilterType::kAverage, {.average_config = FilterAverageConfig::kWindowSize64}}
};

